# Unable to compare IEnumerable object as string

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, ienumerable

I am using below code:

```
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync(); 
var condition = "test";       
do
{
          foreach (User user in users)
          {
               if(number){
                condition = user.BusinessPhones.ToString();
               }
              else{
               condition=user.DisplayName;
               }

              if (condition.Contains("1234"))
              {
                Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);     
                Console.WriteLine(user.BusinessPhones.ToString());

              }
       }
 }
```

Where user.BusinessPhones is of type:-

```
public IEnumerable<string> BusinessPhones { get; set; }
```

But ,i have a condition variable "condition"  which is based on several if else statements(i am only showing 2 in above example).

condition = user.BusinessPhones.ToString(); doesn't work ,but else condition works.
So , please help me achieving the result as i am a beginner in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do here. What do you expect `condition` to be if `BusinessPhones` has multiple phone numbers? Or no phone numbers?

Comment: `BusinessPhones.ToString()` will return the string representation of object, not the actual value, something like that `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`. To get a values from collection you should enumerate it

Comment: hi AllTech, there is no need to write those If statements you have there, you can further optimize your code, see my post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *LINQ* like this

*From the set of users, select their Business Phones if a condition is true else select their display names, check if the selected value contains 154 if yes add it to a list, enumerate the list and print each value*

```
bool number = true;
var users = new List<User>
{
    new User{DisplayName="User1",BusinessPhones= new [] { "1111","2222","3333"} },
    new User{DisplayName="User2",BusinessPhones= new [] { "4444","2222","5555"} },
    new User{DisplayName="User3",BusinessPhones= new [] { "6666","6666","5555"} },
    new User{DisplayName="User4",BusinessPhones= new [] { "7777","6666","1111"} },
};

// var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
var userFilter = users                  
                .Where(u => (number) ? u.BusinessPhones.Contains("6666"): u.DisplayName.Any() ).ToList();

userFilter.ForEach( x=>  Console.WriteLine(string.Join("," ,x.BusinessPhones) + " " + x.DisplayName) ) ;
```

**Output**

```
6666,6666,5555 User3
7777,6666,1111 User4
```

Comment: I changed variable number to true and then modified condit.contains Phone Number, userFilter  is not getting any value then again i changed number to false and condit.contains("User") then also userFilter  doesn't show any value.

Comment: @AllTech Lets continue our discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208589/room-for-clint-and-alltech)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign list of strings (number phones) to the `condition` variable, then you can use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```cs
condition = string.Join(", ", user.BusinessPhones);
```

On example, if we assume that user.BusinessPhones has values "a", "b" and "c", result of `string.Join` will be `a, b, c`.

Comment: Thanks , it works , but now                         Console.WriteLine(user.BusinessPhones.ToString());
is not getting printed. (Updated in question)

Comment: You can do the same, eg. `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", user.BusinessPhones));`